We are performing maintenance on our authentication service on November 19th
On November 19th, 2024 (next Tuesday), we’ll be performing maintenance on our authentication service, which controls user sessions and logins, in order to migrate it to Google Cloud Platform. We expect this maintenance to occur during morning business hours, Eastern time. This post will be updated if the migration is meaningfully delayed, and will be updated when the migration is complete.
If the maintenance goes according to plan, users should not encounter any issues logging into or out of the site, or maintaining their logged-in status. However, in the event that the planned maintenance fails, there is a small chance that users will not be able to log into the network for a short period of time while we roll back the change.
This maintenance is a component of a larger migration to Google Cloud Platform occurring on the Stack Exchange network.

Update: the migration is complete and looks stable. We will continue to monitor over the next few days to ensure the deployment remains stable and error-free.

Eastern time means in the USA, I assume, can you please give the equivalent in UTC time?

UTC is +4 to EST. US Business Hours are roughly 0900 to 1700, so UTC about 1300-2100.
